# If pointer of a COM interface assigned to a CComPtr object do I need to Release the original one?

Tags: c++, com, atl

If I create the pointer of any COM interface and then assign it to an object of `CComPtr` of same COM Interface do I need to release the original COM pointer?

```
ISomeComInterface* pSomeComInterface = new CSomeComInterfaceImplemented();
CComPtr<ISomeComInterface> cptrSomeComInterface = pSomeComInterface;

// ....
// Do I need to Release original COM Pointer.
pSomeComInterface->Release();
```

Comment: Did you implement `CSomeComInterfaceImplemented`? Or know how its reference counting works? Does this ctor create a non-COM pointer with a COM reference ount of one?

Comment: class CSomeComInterfaceImplemented implements the interface ISomeComInterface which is derived (indirectorly) from IUnknown interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CComPtr` takes care of reference count of its internal interface pointer, managed by the instance of the class. It has no effect on reference counts of other pointers. That is, having assigned the pointer to the variable, you can be sure that `CComPtr`'s internal pointer is `AddRef`'ded and `Release`'d as necessary, however you should take care of your raw interface pointer variable `pSomeComInterface` yourself and make explicit `Release` call.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may need release the previous pointer;

> `CComPtr::operator =`
>
> This operation AddRefs the new object and releases the existing object, if one exists.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98t6xe11.aspx). `CComPtr` is used to manage the lifetime of the COM object (it applies the RAII idiom to COM objects) - it manages the reference count itself.

However, the technique you are using to create the COM object is unusual and it seems to not perform the `AddRef()`; hence in this case the `Release()` would not be needed.

The common manner to create a COM object with `CComPtr` is to use the [`CoCreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/810b85cb.aspx) method of `CComPtr`. In which case the `AddRef()` and `Release()` methods are managed by the `CComPtr` and should not be called by your client code.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the COM object constructor initializes the reference count. Most likely it sets it to zero so you don't need an extra `Release()` call. `CComPtr` will then take care of the object.

Look into how the COM object initializes the reference count to be sure. It's not illegal to set the reference count to anything other than zero, the only requirement is that once the object pointer is returned to COM client the reference count is set to one and ownership is so passed to the client. Strictly speaking because you `new` the object instead of calling `CoCreateInstance()` or calling a method of a COM object you're not guaranteed any specific value.

So the following could be legal *if reference count is set to one in object constructor*:

```
HRESULT ComMethod( Type** result )
{
    if( result == 0 ) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }
    //refcount set to 1 in constructor,
    //so no AddRef() call
    *result = new Type();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that COM even requires an explicit reference count, let alone a reference count of one. In particular, I think COM can co-exist with non-COM references such as `shared_ptr`. COM merely requires that you do not delete the object as long as COM has references; it doesn't require the object to be destructed immediately after the last COM reference is Release'd.

Comment: @MSalters Maybe, but it then means you cannot be sure some object is "destroyed" and the system state is changed accordingly - some "file" or "mutex" object might remain alive infinitely long even though you've released all the references.

Comment: True, but that's not a concern to COM, that's application-level logic.  And I think you can't be sure that objects are immediately destroyed in DCOM (distributed COM) anyway. For performance reasons, DCOM doesn't check if the other side is still alive so you may temporarily have stale references. This is valid for COM because the semantics prevent early destruction but allow late destruction.